# Interrupting a function on qt button press

Tags: c++

I have a function that could run in an infinite loop, so I need a way of stopping the function at the press of a button. The problem is that while the function is running, the Qt widgets become unresponsive so I can't just set a stop bool when the button is pressed.

I am unsure of how to do this: 
Connect the button signal to a QEventLoop and use that to stop the function (don't know how that would work) or have the function in a separate thread (never done that before)?

Comment: Read QThread class documentation. I'm pretty sure that after reading it you will know how to do this.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into that.